# Как обновить кнопку при обновлении данных переменной Kivy Python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, kivy

Есть небольшой код, как сделать так что бы текст кнопки 1 менялся каждый раз когда переменная изменит своё значение на другое, например у меня есть переменная которая получает курс валют rub/usd через api, как сделать что бы текст кнопки 1 сравнивался со старым значением переменной курса валют и менял текст кнопки автоматически на новый ?

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.lang import Builder
from kivy.uix.boxlayout import BoxLayout
from kivy.properties import StringProperty
from kivy.uix.button import Button


KV = """
MyBL:
    orientation: "vertical"
    size_hint: (0.95, 0.95)
    pos_hint: {"center_x": 0.5, "center_y":0.5}

    Label:
        font_size: "30sp"
        text: root.data_label

    Button:
        text: root.text_btn1
        bold: True
        backgroung_color: "#00FFCE"
        size_hint: (1,0.5)
        on_press: root.callback()

    Button:
        text: "2"
        bold: True
        backgroung_color: "#00FFCE"
        size_hint: (1,0.5)
        on_press: root.callback1()
"""

class MyBL(BoxLayout):
    data_label = StringProperty("Главный текст")
    text_btn1 = "1"

    def callback(self):
        print("1")

    def callback1(self):
        print("2")

class MyApp(App):
    def build(self):
        return Builder.load_string(KV)

    
if __name__ == "__main__":
    MyApp().run()
```

Comment: а где собственно эта переменная валюты?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Не совсем мог понять ваш вопрос, но предположим, что в промежутке какого-то времени вы опрашивайте API на получение курса валют, а далее хотите вывести значение курса как надпись на кнопке. В таком случае вам может помочь использование `from kivy.clock import Clock`. Мы зададим некоторый промежуток времени, в котором будем опрашивать внутреннюю процедуру класса `MyBL`, а затем обновлять текст нашей кнопки.

В качестве функции возвращающая значение курса, я буду использовать модуль `Random` и возвращать значения от 1 до 100, в своём примере вы можете проинициализировать собственную функцию, которая будет возвращать курс валют, нам главное понять, как вызвать и присвоить данное значение как текст к кнопке.

Дополним наш класс `MyBL` Следующими вещами:

```
    def update_button_text(self, new_text): 
    #обновляем текст кнопки (используем её при каллбэке нажатия на кнопку 1 (`callback1`)
        self.text_btn1 = new_text

    def update_random_number(self, dt):
    #создаем переменную со случайным числом, но тут вы можете собственно объявить переменную курса валют
    #и присваиваем её к тексту кнопки
        new_random_number = str(random.randint(1, 100))
        self.text_btn1 = new_random_number
```

Дополним наш `callback1`

```
def callback(self):
        print("1")
        self.update_button_text("New Text")  # Изменяем надпись кнопки при нажатии
```

Далее создадим в классе нашего приложения (`MyApp`) хандлер `on_start`, толкая в него создадние клока с ивентом обновления текста кнопки случайным числом

```
def on_start(self):
        # Запускаем таймер с интервалом в 1 секунду для обновления текста кнопки
        Clock.schedule_interval(self.root.update_random_number, 1)
```

Не забываем дополнить импорт

```
from kivy.clock import Clock
```

Теперь, при нажатии на кнопку, кнопка принимает текст `New Text`, а каждую секунду надпись кнопки изменяется на случайное число от 1 до 100.

До нажатия выглядит так (не запишу вам анимацию, уж поверьте или проверьте, там меняются значения каждую секунду)

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

После нажатия на 1 секунду.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

---

Полный код для вас

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.lang import Builder
from kivy.uix.boxlayout import BoxLayout
from kivy.properties import StringProperty
from kivy.uix.button import Button
from kivy.clock import Clock
import random

KV = """
MyBL:
    orientation: "vertical"
    size_hint: (0.95, 0.95)
    pos_hint: {"center_x": 0.5, "center_y":0.5}

    Label:
        font_size: "30sp"
        text: root.data_label

    Button:
        text: root.text_btn1
        bold: True
        background_color: "#00FFCE"
        size_hint: (1,0.5)
        on_press: root.callback()

    Button:
        text: "2"
        bold: True
        background_color: "#00FFCE"
        size_hint: (1,0.5)
        on_press: root.callback1()
"""

class MyBL(BoxLayout):
    data_label = StringProperty("Главный текст")
    text_btn1 = StringProperty("1")

    def callback(self):
        print("1")
        self.update_button_text("New Text")  # Изменяем надпись кнопки при нажатии

    def callback1(self):
        print("2")

    def update_button_text(self, new_text): 
    #обновляем текст кнопки (используем её при каллбэке нажатия на кнопку 1 (`callback1`)
        self.text_btn1 = new_text

    def update_random_number(self, dt):
    #создаем переменную со случайным числом, но тут вы можете собственно объявить переменную курса валют
    #и присваиваем её к тексту кнопки
        new_random_number = str(random.randint(1, 100))
        self.text_btn1 = new_random_number

class MyApp(App):
    def build(self):
        return Builder.load_string(KV)

    def on_start(self):
        # Запускаем таймер с интервалом в 1 секунду для обновления текста кнопки
        Clock.schedule_interval(self.root.update_random_number, 1)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    MyApp().run()
```

Comment: Спасибо за ваш ответ, это то что я хотел, даже больше )